# How can I change the representation of 2-dimensional arrays in the debugging mode of eclipse?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, debugging

As you can see in the picture is a variable called board. It's defined as:

```
int board[][] = new int[10][10]
```

I'd like to have a representation like this:

```
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Or even better without the brackets and just commas and if possible also that there are arranged like if you'd use:

```
printf("%3", board[i][j])
```

To print it as there might be numbers > 10, e.g. with different numbers of characters.

I have seen something very similar some time ago, unfortunately I don't have a screenshot of it.

[image: I have an array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a feature called [detail formatters](http://www.robertwloch.net/2012/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-detail-formatter/) that allow you to write a custom snippet of display code for *non-primitive types*. Sounds great, right?

Unfortunately, this won't solve your problem directly because it is not applicable for primitive types or [arrays](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323962). Eclipse always uses its builtin formatters for those types.

You do have a couple of options, however. Perhaps this array is a member of a containing class - in which case you could either add a `toString()` method which formats the array in the way you'd like, or add a detail formatter for this type, as described above (e.g., because the `toString()` method may already implemented in a different way that you cannot change).

If that's not the case, the best approach I know of is to still write your formatting method, say `String ArrayFormatter.format2D(int[][] array)` and then use the [*Expressions* view](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fexpressions%2Fref-expressions_view.htm) to make a call to this method with your array, like:

```
ArrayFormatter.format2D(board)
```

Then the expressions view will show you the formatted output whenever `board` is in scope. These expressions persist across debugging runs, so you only have to set this up once.

Comment: toString() worked just fine. As I did some research on my own I stumbled about these detail formatters aswell. You don't know by any chance any better "tutorial" about them as the link mentioned? It's a bit minimal...I had a look on it already.

Comment: It's a pretty minimal because I think detail formatters are pretty straightforward. In fact, the tutorial is perhaps a bit longer than it needs to be since it is covering the "development" of your details formatter. Here's the very simple version I just tried: Open Eclipse create an empty class `Foo` and a main method like `Foo f = new Foo(); f.hashCode();`. Put a breakpoint on the `hashCode` line and Debug. In the _Variables_ view, right click `f` and choose "New Detail Formatter...". Enter `return "hotdog";` and save. Done - the display for `f` now shows "hotdog". @Felix.C

Comment: If you have a specific issue about detail formatters, you could create a another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You should encapsulate it in a class and implement its `toString()` method.

Eclipse has its very basic way to present an array, you cannot change this.

More about `toString()` [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method).